# Appropriate \minipage width

Tags: margins, minipage, fbox

I was using `minipage` inside `fbox`, and got an overfull hbox. I know that it is common practice to set the width of `minipage` inside `fbox` as `\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep`, but the hbox is still overfull. Here is a MWE below.

```
\documentclass{report}%

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\noindent\fbox{
    \rule{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}{1cm}
}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I don't really get the appropriate width; that is, the maximum width without making overfull hboxes; of `minipage`. Can someone help me out?

++ I also see that the left and top margins of hbox in the example are quite different, but I'm not sure if this is meant to be like this since I don't know much about `rule`.

Comment: The `framed` package might help. Further, it can break across pages.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I should have put `%` after `fbox{` and `end{minipage}`. That somehow counts as space. After that everything works fine.

Comment: ends of lines are always treated as spaces you can write `one two` with a space between or a newline between, and either way it typesets as one two with a space between the words.